# Dividing in pandas with different date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, format

I have these two dataframes:

```
data
Out[38]: 
              Dollars
date                           
1980-12-31          1596.144444
1981-12-31          1678.686538
1982-12-31          1829.826923
1983-12-31          2050.459615
1984-12-31          2218.105660
1985-12-31          2413.930769
1986-12-31          2615.113462

population
Out[39]: 
1960-01-01    180671000.0
1961-01-01    183691000.0
1962-01-01    186538000.0
1963-01-01    189242000.0
1964-01-01    191889000.0
1965-01-01    194303000.0
1966-01-01    196560000.0
1967-01-01    198712000.0
1968-01-01    200706000.0
1969-01-01    202677000.0
1970-01-01    205052000.0
```

My issue is that i cannot just divide `data/population` since the dates are in one case on thirty first of the month and the second case it is on the first of the month. Same for the month, in one case it is jan and the other case it is on Dec of the year. How can i reconcile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-format the index of the `data` dataframe by setting the `date` to the first day of the month of January with this line:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.year, format = '%Y')
```

Check this code as an example:

```
# import
import pandas as pd

# dataframe loading
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# optionally setting 'date' as index, if not already done
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)

# optionally convert index type from 'str' to 'datetime', if not already done
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

# resetting date to the first day of the month
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.year, format = '%Y')
```

Output:

```
            Dollars    
date                   
1980-01-01  1596.144444
1981-01-01  1678.686538
1982-01-01  1829.826923
1983-01-01  2050.459615
1984-01-01  2218.105660
1985-01-01  2413.930769
1986-01-01  2615.113462
```

Then you can proceed with further data manipulation.